# Ubuntu 20.04 takes too much time to boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, hp, startup

I asked this question before but the answers didn't work for me. I even reinstall the ubuntu 20.04 but no change

`systemd-analyze blame` output

> 40.596s plymouth-quit-wait.service
> 23.558s snapd.service
> 22.471s networkd-dispatcher.service
> 18.067s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
> 13.555s dev-sda2.device
> 13.236s apport-autoreport.service
> 12.648s udisks2.service
> 10.391s accounts-daemon.service
> 10.272s ModemManager.service
> 8.740s dev-loop18.device
> 8.117s dev-loop25.device
> 8.088s dev-loop8.device
> 8.086s dev-loop9.device
> 8.084s dev-loop13.device
> 8.084s dev-loop15.device
> 8.081s dev-loop16.device
> 8.081s dev-loop22.device
> 8.079s dev-loop21.device
> 8.078s dev-loop24.device
> 8.022s dev-loop6.device
> 8.018s dev-loop11.device
> 8.017s dev-loop17.device
> 8.014s dev-loop19.device
> 8.012s dev-loop23.device
> 7.985s dev-loop27.device
> 7.927s dev-loop26.device
> 7.769s polkit.service
> 7.419s avahi-daemon.service
> 7.417s bluetooth.service
> 7.412s NetworkManager.service
> 7.018s switcheroo-control.service
> 7.008s thermald.service
> 7.004s systemd-logind.service
> 7.003s wpa_supplicant.service
> 6.031s dev-loop5.device
> 5.808s dev-loop4.device
> 5.786s dev-loop3.device
> 5.661s fwupd.service
> 5.535s dev-loop20.device
> 5.401s dev-loop10.device
> 5.353s dev-loop14.device
> 5.089s bolt.service
> 5.032s dev-loop12.device
> 4.712s systemd-rfkill.service
> 3.716s dev-loop0.device
> 3.328s gpu-manager.service
> 3.317s dev-loop1.device
> 3.316s grub-common.service
> 3.316s dev-loop2.device
> 3.313s dev-loop7.device
> 3.168s gdm.service
> 3.056s preload.service
> 3.046s systemd-resolved.service
> 2.889s apport.service
> 2.504s e2scrub_reap.service
> 2.501s rsyslog.service
> 1.965s systemd-sysctl.service
> 1.877s grub-initrd-fallback.service
> 1.797s apparmor.service
> 1.521s snap-android\x2dstudio-91.mount
> 1.498s snapd.apparmor.service
> 1.463s snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-95.mount
> 1.444s snap-core-9804.mount
> 1.381s snap-core-9993.mount
> 1.367s snap-core18-1705.mount
> 1.350s snap-core18-1885.mount
> 1.349s snap-discord-112.mount
> 1.308s snap-discord-115.mount
> 1.307s snap-figma\x2dlinux-86.mount
> 1.278s snap-gimp-292.mount
> 1.034s pppd-dns.service
> 991ms snap-gimp-297.mount
> 968ms systemd-modules-load.service
> 947ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount
> 903ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount
> 897ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
> 836ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
> 821ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount
> 820ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount
> 795ms upower.service
> 776ms snap-inkscape-7921.mount
> 742ms snap-inkscape-7947.mount
> 734ms swapfile.swap
> 714ms systemd-sysusers.service
> 711ms packagekit.service
> 701ms systemd-udevd.service
> 674ms keyboard-setup.service
> 655ms snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dcommunity-249.mount
> 620ms systemd-journald.service
> 609ms snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dcommunity-252.mount
> 582ms openvpn.service
> 559ms modprobe@drm.service
> 517ms systemd-random-seed.service
> 505ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dcore18-32.mount
> 473ms systemd-timesyncd.service
> 386ms kerneloops.service
> 382ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
> 345ms snap-rambox-13.mount
> 331ms snap-simplenote-384.mount
> 318ms snap-snap\x2dstore-433.mount
> 289ms snap-snap\x2dstore-467.mount
> 261ms dev-hugepages.mount
> 260ms dev-mqueue.mount
> 258ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
> 257ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
> 254ms kmod-static-nodes.service
> 247ms snapd.seeded.service
> 245ms snap-snapd-8790.mount
> 229ms ufw.service
> 227ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7D17\x2d84A2.service
> 201ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
> 201ms snap-snapd-9279.mount
> 194ms user@1000.service
> 190ms systemd-user-sessions.service
> 187ms systemd-journal-flush.service
> 170ms console-setup.service
> 140ms colord.service
> 135ms snap-vlc-1700.mount
> 132ms systemd-remount-fs.service
> 129ms boot-efi.mount
> 126ms setvtrgb.service
> 119ms systemd-update-utmp.service
> 113ms plymouth-start.service
> 113ms snap-youtube\x2ddl-2846.mount
> 61ms plymouth-read-write.service
> 51ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
> 45ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
> 39ms alsa-restore.service
> 11ms rtkit-daemon.service
> 4ms sys-kernel-config.mount
> 4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
> 1ms snapd.socket

`systemd-analyze` output

`Startup finished in 4.561s (firmware) + 4.370s (loader) + 3.831s (kernel) + 1min 10.958s (userspace) = 1min 23.722s  graphical.target reached after 1min 10.825s in userspace`

I get to know that dev-loop is the one responsible for slow bootup which comes with snap.

So if I remove snap will that solve my problem also I have some snap applications (android-studio, Figma, gimp, Inkscape etc.) what will happen to them?

If any other method available I am ready for it.

Comment: Are you booting from HDD or SSD? 13 seconds for mounting is abnormally slow, even for HDD.

Comment: its HDD and windows boot normally but ubuntu takes this huge time to boot. IDK why!!